# Add one name to Select

Tags: sql, select, asp-classic

i have this sql command:

```
SELECT Jmeno, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN Ucast = 'TRUE' then 1 end) as Pocet_zapasu, 
SUM(CASE WHEN Branky>=0 then Branky end) as branek 
FROM Hraci 
INNER JOIN Ucast_Zapas ON Ucast_Zapas.ID_Hrace_zapas=Hraci.IDHrace  
INNER JOIN Zapas ON Zapas.ID_zapas=Ucast_Zapas.ID_zapasu_ucast  
INNER JOIN Kategorie ON Kategorie.IDkategorie=Zapas.Kategorie_zapas  
WHERE (Zapas.Druh=1) GROUP BY Jmeno
```

But when i use this command in listview:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Icons/edit.png" PostBackUrl='<%#string.Format("/Default3.aspx?id={0}",Eval("IDHrace"))%>' />
```

I have this error:

```
 DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'IDHrace'.
```

Because in the sqlcommand missing the Hraci.IDHrace...But I dont know why i give Hraci.IDHrace to previous sqlcommand..
Have you any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query doesn't return `IDHrace`.

You should include it in your `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT 
Hraci.IDHrace,
Jmeno, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN Ucast = 'TRUE' then 1 end) as Pocet_zapasu, 
SUM(CASE WHEN Branky>=0 then Branky end) as branek 
FROM Hraci 
INNER JOIN Ucast_Zapas ON Ucast_Zapas.ID_Hrace_zapas=Hraci.IDHrace  
INNER JOIN Zapas ON Zapas.ID_zapas=Ucast_Zapas.ID_zapasu_ucast  
INNER JOIN Kategorie ON Kategorie.IDkategorie=Zapas.Kategorie_zapas  
WHERE (Zapas.Druh=1) GROUP BY Jmeno, Hraci.IDHRace
```

Comment: This is i try first, but i have this error:  Column 'Hraci.IDHrace' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @Kate - add it to the group by (I've updated my answer to show you how).

Answer (score 0):

You need to select `IDHrace` in your sql statement